# How do I know that OneToMany relation has been changed?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have the following entities:

```
class Person
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * 
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="PersonEmail", mappedBy="person", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    private $emails;

    /**
     * @var datetime $updated
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $updated;
}
```

.

```
class PersonEmail
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="email", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Person", inversedBy="emails")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="person_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    private $person;
}
```

I use Symfony2 form builder to create forms. After the form is submitted I call `$form->bind($request)`. And my question is: how do I know that the emails are changed (inserted, updated or deleted) before I save the Person entity? I need it because I want to update Person::$updated field. I can do it when the Person entity is modified itself using PreUpdate lifecycle callback, but how can I update this field when only email list was changed? Predicting the easiest answer: I would like to avoid updating this field when nothing is changed at all.

Updating the Person entity in the PersonEmail's lifecycle callback is not possible, since the Person entity is already processed at that moment.

Controller code (not sure if it helps):

```
/**
 * 
 * @Template()
 */
public function editAction($id, Request $request)
{
    $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AcmeBundle:Person');
    $person = $repository->find($id);
    if (!$person) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('No person found for id '.$id);
    }
    if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
        $form->bind($request);
        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
            $em->flush();
        }
    }
    return array('form' => $form->createView(), 'person' => $person);
}
```

Comment: Can you post your controller's code?

Comment: Why don't you in your controller check that `$originalperson->emails === $person->emails` after `$form->bind($request)` and if not, just call `$person->updated = new \DateTime()`?

Comment: Can you explain what is $originalperson? And are you serious about comparing objects using the identity operator (===)? JFYI, the official php documentation states: `when using the identity operator (===), object variables are identical if and only if they refer to the same instance of the same class. ` What results do you expect to get after using this operator?

Comment: `$originalperson` is what you get when you call `$repository->find($id)`. You then check if the binded object's (`$person`) `emails` property has changed and if yes you update the `updated` property. JFMI what's `$emails` (yep, can't guess what you don't write)?

Comment: I'm surprised to hear such a question about the field type, but ok. Obviously `$emails` being `OneToMany` relation is a collection of type `Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection` or `Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection` for the persistent entity state. What type could it have if not a collection? Regarding the `$originalperson`, are you suggesting me to do this: `$originalperson = clone $person;`? Or what is your idea?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check if entity is changed in Doctrine 2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10800178/how-to-check-if-entity-is-changed-in-doctrine-2)

Comment: Well, I saw that question. But as to my point of view it is not exactly the same, since I was looking for a way to check changes after form binding rather than during the `flush()` call. However, it seems that there is no better _native_ way.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution. It's not that elegant as I was hoping to get, but anyway at least it works. So, in my solution we first check if the emails collection is dirty (meaning that some emails were added and/or deleted). If it's not dirty we still need to check if any changes to the existing emails were made. I was hoping to use some existing API for that, but it seems there are none of them for this case. So, I decided to check my data manually for changes. Code example follows.

```
/**
 * 
 * @Template()
 */
public function editAction($id, Request $request)
{
    $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AcmeBundle:Person');
    $person = $repository->find($id);
    if (!$person) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('No person found for id '.$id);
    }
    if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
        $form->bind($request);
        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();

            // isDirty() will be true if emails were added or deleted
            if ($person->getEmails()->isDirty()) {
                $person->setUpdated(new \DateTime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s')));
            } else {
                $uow = $em->getUnitOfWork();

                // as no one suggested a working solution, I just decided
                // to check entity by entity, field by field
                // if anything is changed, we'll mark $person as updated
                foreach($person->getEmails() as $item) {
                    $orig = $uow->getOriginalEntityData($item);
                    if ($item->getEmail() != $orig['email']) {
                        $person->setUpdated(new \DateTime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s')));
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            $em->flush();
        }
    }
    return array('form' => $form->createView(), 'person' => $person);
}
```

If anyone has any idea how to avoid one by one entity check, I would greatly appreciate if you share such a solution.