# Symfony3 save every update into database

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony

I´m new on symfony and postgreSQL and I´m trying to save a log of database updates/deletes 
I´ve created this table

```
CREATE TABLE  "public"."changes" (
  "id" INT NOT NULL ,
  "id_user" INT NOT NULL,
  "operation" VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  "table" VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  "column" VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  "old_data" TEXT NOT NULL,
  "new_data" TEXT NOT NULL,
  "ts" TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY ("id"),
  CONSTRAINT "user"
    FOREIGN KEY ("id_user")
    REFERENCES "public"."users" ("id")
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION);
```

And what I need is to save into this table every time I do sumething like

```
/**
 * @Route("/insert", name="insert")
 */
public function insertAction(Request $request)
{
    $em = $this->get('doctrine')->getManager();

    $info = new Info();
    $info->setMail($request->request->get('mail'));
    $info->setName($request->request->get('name'));
    $info->setLastname($request->request->get('lastname'));

    $em->persist($info);

    $em->flush();

}
```

I´m thinking about creating an object/array with the table/column/data and after the flush if everything is ok, call a global function to add the data into the changes table.
Is there a easy way / good practice to do this?

Comment: can't you just do it un a postUpdate listener ?

Comment: how to? I made a store procedure into a database, but I need to made this also from code because I need to save the user that´s making the change

Comment: We did that by using Postgres’ [`LISTEN`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-listen.html) & [`NOTIFY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-notify.html) feature so the logging is handled by [another process](http://www.pomm-project.org/news/using-postgresql-notify-in-5-minutes.html).

Comment: sorry but don´t understand, can you give me an example?

Comment: I have added the links to the doc & an example.

Comment: Thanks @greg that´s good to know, but it´s not what i´m looking for

Comment: [PrePersist and postPersist event listener on an entity](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/jbm8/prepersist-and-postpersist-event-listener-on-an-entity) and [Logging field changes with a trigger like event listener for auditing purposes](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/ew0r/logging-field-changes-with-a-trigger-like-event-listener-for-auditing-purposes) and [OnFlush event listener on an entity](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/oymp/onflush-event-listener-on-an-entity) and many more in that blog!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you don't need to implement this king of logic yourself. Doctrine tracks entity insertions, updates, field changes and deletes internally, and creates corresponding events that you can listen to. For instance, when you create new `Info` entity and persist it, Doctrine will dispatch `prePersist` event when you call `flush` operation. You could create event subscriber to subscribe on such events and do your logic there.

To fully understand Doctrine lifecycle events check out official doctrine documentation: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html

Event subscriber creation described in the Symfony documentation: http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html#creating-the-subscriber-class

Also you can try out existing third-party bundle that will log entity insertions, updates and deletes: https://github.com/simplethings/EntityAuditBundle It also supports versioning.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I´m having lot of problems implementing this. Can you give me a hand? I created a listener where I can get the entity and entityManager, but how to work with this?

Comment: Hi Vadim Ashikhman, thanks for your answer. Didn´t answer you before, because I was make lot of research about It. But I´m stuck. What I made is a suscriber postupdate with, for example, user/roles tables. But here is my first issue. Lets say I want to change the role of the user, how can I save the old role and the new one inside my changes table? How can I know what table i´m using to say it, or what column has changed?

Comment: Hey! In the `preUpdate` event call `getEntityChangeSet` method on the event object and you will get every changed field. Here is some documentation on the `preUpdate` event http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#preupdate

Comment: Thanks again, Look at this: https://gist.github.com/braianj/3b375c0eb5ab9b5983a8aea46a7788a3 With this I can get the old and new data. But I get some problems with collections: for example let´s say I need to change the user role, how can I save that info into database. I have no problem with other kind of info, but with foreign key I´m stuck. Thanks again

Comment: Why not using `postFlush()` as you can be sure the changeSet contains really and actually changed values? If you call preUpdate you can never be sure the change actually took place, do you?